# How to create a semi "fully connected" network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I can create a fully connected network with 10 layers as follows:

```
# input
input_tensor = torch.rand(1, 10)

# model's weights
l1 = torch.rand(input_tensor.shape[1], 32)
l2 = torch.rand(32, 32)
l3 = torch.rand(32, 32)
l4 = torch.rand(32, 32)
l5 = torch.rand(32, 32)
l6 = torch.rand(32, 32)
l7 = torch.rand(32, 32)
l8 = torch.rand(32, 32)
l9 = torch.rand(32, 32)
l10 = torch.rand(32, 32)

# "forward" function (no biases in this example but optimally they should be used)
l1_out = torch.sin(torch.mm(input_tensor, l1))
l2_out = torch.sin(torch.mm(l1_out, l2))
l3_out = torch.sin(torch.mm(l2_out, l3))
l4_out = torch.sin(torch.mm(l3_out, l4))
l5_out = torch.sin(torch.mm(l4_out, l5))
l6_out = torch.sin(torch.mm(l5_out, l6))
l7_out = torch.sin(torch.mm(l6_out, l7))
l8_out = torch.sin(torch.mm(l7_out, l8))
l9_out = torch.sin(torch.mm(l8_out, l9))
l10_out = torch.sin(torch.mm(l9_out, l10))
```

But how can I create a semi "fully connected" network? Meaning, each neuron is **not** connected to every neuron in the following layer. I want to specify a percentage (e.g., `0.1`), which will correspond to how many neurons each neuron will be connected to in the following layer.

So for example, if `percentage=0.1` and I have 100 neurons in each layer, each neuron should be connected to 10 **random** neurons in the next layer.

I can do this very inefficiently by selecting a random `percentage * num_neurons` indices for each neuron in each layer and then use a `for loop` to multiply the weights (e.g., see this [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437989/implementing-sparse-connections-in-neural-network?rq=2)). But this is highly inefficient and does not use the GPU.

Ideally this will also work with orthogonal initialization of the weights:

```
l2 = nn.init.orthogonal_(torch.empty(32, 32))
```

Comment: Well, not going to delve to deep here, but see [dropout](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Dropout.html). Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @null thanks for the comment! Dropout/ any other masking will still require having a "fully connected" number of parameters, which I'm trying to avoid. The whole point is that this should be much more efficient

Comment: I don't really get what you mean though you try to decrease parameters ? You still can with dropout ? I mean you want 100 neurons layer to connect 10 random neurons in the next layer, but how much do they overlap you can decrease this by making the next layer as say 40 neurons, no?

Comment: Yes, part of this method will reduce the number of weights, as each neuron is not required to be connected to each other neuron in the next layer. Masking/dropout will not prevent that as you just multiply the existing weights by 0. Regarding the overlap, that's going to be dependent on the `percentage`. For example, if the `percentage=1` it will just be a fully connected network, as each neuron is connected to each other neuron. This also have mathematical properties that are beyond reducing parameters, hence reducing 100 neurons to 40 defeats the purpose

Comment: @Penguin use PyTorch's `nn.Linear` module along with masking techniques

Comment: Adding to Afzal, masking would work the best. You can make a masking matrix, where you can specify which parameters you will null out and which you can keep. I think that is exactly what you need if you want to specify manually what you want to keep.

Comment: I think you should rethink your approach overall. It seems like your motivation is to reduce the number of weights - this is best done by making the layers smaller. Computing a bunch of "dead" neurons that you don't intend to use for anything doesn't make sense. If you want sparsity, you can use L1 regularization/pruning.